# Re-run application sq lite database deleted in cordova

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working in cordova. I created one database and table in it. It's work perfectly. But When I run application again database is not exist. It was deleted. I am using sqlite plugin  [https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/storesafe/cordova-sqlite-storage)

Please help me. I wasted my lots of time for that didn't get any solution.

My code for create database

```
define([
    'cordova',
    'logs'
], function () {
    SQLiteDB = function () {
        var self = this;
        this.dbName = 'AppDb.s3db';
        this.db = null;

        /*
            Populate database
        */
        this.openDatabase = function (callback) {
            this.db = sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
                name: this.dbName, location: 2, createFromLocation: 1
            });

            this.db.transaction(
                function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myDB(pax_id integer primary key, user_token text)');

                    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                        callback.call();
                    }
                },
                this.dbErrorHandler
            );
        },
        this.addLoginDetail = function (pax_id, user_token, successCallback) {
            var that = this;

            if (!this.db)
                this.openDatabase();

            that.db.transaction(
                function (tx) {  
                    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO myDB (pax_id, user_token) VALUES (?,?)", [pax_id, user_token], function (tx, res) {
                        console.log("Save device config to local database");
                        Logs.logWrite("Save device config to local database");

                        if (typeof successCallback == 'function') {
                            var config_settings = null;
                            config_settings = JSON.parse(val.CONFIG_SETTINGS);
                            config_settings.LAST_UPDATE_TIME = lastUpdateTime;

                            if (!config_settings.APP_TYPE)
                                config_settings.APP_TYPE = 'D';

                            successCallback.call(config_settings);
                        }

                    });          
                },
                that.dbErrorHandler
            )
        }

        this.getLoginDetail = function (successCallback) {
            var that = this;
            console.log('call Login detail in local database');
            Logs.logWrite('call getEmployee in local database');

            if (!this.db)
                this.openDatabase();

            this.db.transaction(
                function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql("SELECT pax_id, user_token from myDB;", [],
                        function (tx, res) {
                            if (typeof successCallback == 'function') {
                                var employee = null;
                                var config_settings = null;
                                if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                                    config_settings = JSON.parse(res.rows.item(0).config_settings);
                                    console.log("dbLogin =============>> " + JSON.stringify(config_settings));
                                    employee = res.rows.item(0);
                                }
                                successCallback.call(config_settings);
                            }
                        },
                        that.dbErrorHandler
                    )
                },
                that.dbErrorHandler
            );
        }
    }
    return SQLiteDB;
});
```

Comment: Which cordova version you are using ? I had this issue in earlier cordova versions.

Comment: cordova version - 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Updating your cordova version should resolve the issue.

and keep in mind that WebSQL API is depricated. It is unlikely to ever be supported on platforms that don't currently support it, and it may be removed from platforms that do.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solved. Thanks!!